# Efficient estimation of the parameter of the binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a sample from the binomial distribution with parameters $(m,p)$, with known parameter $m$. I need to find the Fisher information $i(p)$ in the given model and find a effective estimation of the parameter $p$.

My attempt was the following, I took the function:
$$f_{p}(x) = \prod\limits_{i = 1}^{n}\binom{m}{x_i}p^{x_i}(1-p)^{m - x_i}
$$ Then I considered
$$lnf_{p}(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(ln\binom{m}{x_i} + x_iln(p) + (m-x_i)ln(1-p))
$$ After taking the derivative I get
$$\frac{\partial lnf_{p}(x)}{\partial p} = \frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i + \frac{mn}{1-p} - \frac{1}{1-p}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i = \frac{1-2p}{p(1-p)}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i + \frac{mn}{(1-p)} =\frac{n}{1-p}(\frac{1-2p}{np}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i+m) = \frac{n}{(1-p)p}(\frac{1-2p}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i+pm) = \frac{nm}{(1-p)p}(\frac{1-2p}{nm}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i+p)
$$
And then, from the corollary of the Rao-Kramer inequality, we can state that the effective estimate of the parameter $p$ is $\frac{1-2p}{nm}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$, and the Fisher $i(p)$ information of one observation is equal to $\frac{m}{(1-p)p}$.

I know that the Fisher information is calculated correctly, but the resulting estimation seems wrong to me, since it depends on the unknown parameter $p$. In this case, what is the correct way to find an effective estimation? I would be grateful for any hints.

Comment: The estimation is wrong. You need to put the derivative equal to $0$ and then solve for $p$ the equation.

Comment: The UMVUE is immediate, given that the family is exponential full rank, by Lehman-Scheffe. However, it is unclear to me what you mean with effective estimator.

Comment: @Youem I don’t need to find maximum likelihood estimation, I need to find effective estimation

Comment: @Snoop by the effective estimation I mean such an estimate for which the equality in the Rao-Kramer inequality holds

Comment: you don't get any estimate from calculating the fisher information. It is necessary to come up with a separate "guess" of a reasonable estimate, calculate it's variance and then compare with the Rao-Kramer bound. For example, try the overall mean - as a first guess.

Comment: @P.Jo Actually you’re not right, since equality in the Rao-Kramer inequality is achieved if and only if $(\theta_n(X)-\theta)=c(\theta)\frac{\partial lnf_{\theta}}{\partial \theta}$, where $\theta_n$ is a unbiased estimator of $\theta$

Comment: You can check that the variance of the UMVUE equals $I(p)^{-1}$. However, you must first get $I(p)=nm/(p(1-p))$.

Comment: I guess the exercise has a point to show but you could have used that if $B_1, \ldots, B_k$ are all binomial with the same probability of success, then $B_1 + \ldots + B_k$ is binomial with the same probability of success (the number of attempts being the sum of the indivial numbers). This makes the estimation more straightforward.

Comment: @WilliamM. Could you write your idea broadly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) Let $X=(X_1,...,X_n)$ be an IID sample from the distribution $\textrm{Bin}(m,p)$ where $m$ is known and $p\in [0,1]$ (i.e. the parameter space is of full rank). Then the joint mass function for $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is
$$f_p(x)=e^{\ln(\frac{p}{1-p})\sum_{1\leq k \leq n}x_k+nm\ln(1-p)}\prod_{1\leq k \leq n}\binom{m}{x_k}\mathbf{1}_{\{0,1,...,m\}}(x_k)$$
this is an exponential-type family in $p \in (0,1)$, so that $T(x):=\sum_{1\leq k \leq n}x_k$ is complete and sufficient.

(ii) If we define $h(T(X))=T(X)/(nm)$ then $E[h(T(X))]=p$. So $h(T(X))$ is the UMVUE for $p$ by Lehmann-Scheffé theorem.

(iii) Since $f_p$ is exponential-type and $E[h(T(X))]<\infty$ we have
$$I(p)=-E\bigg[\frac{d^2}{dp^2}\ln f_p(X)\bigg]=-E\bigg[\frac{(2p-1)T(X)}{p^2(1-p)^2}-\frac{nm}{(1-p)^2}\bigg]=\frac{nm}{p(1-p)}$$

(iv) We have $V[h(T(X))]=nmp(1-p)/(n^2m^2)=p(1-p)/(nm)$. We conclude that $I(p)^{-1}=V[h(T(X))]$.

All claims used can be found in [Shao](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97553).

Comment: but is there methods to find efficience estimate without knowing what is complete and sufficient statistics?

Comment: @wxist There exist results to find the UMVUE when a complete sufficient statistic is not available (see Shao section 3.1.2.). If the UMVUE is available, one can assert that it will have the lowest variance among all unbiased estimators. In such case you can check efficiency of the UMVUE if there is the CRLB and it is known. If the CRLB is unknown, but you have the UMVUE, you can be sure that there won't be other unbiased estimators of lower variance regardless of the CRLB issue.